The DIEs in the DWARF information suggests an overlap between two fields
Consider the following C code:
struct all_t {
    unsigned a:13;
    char b;
};

struct all_t all;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    all.b = 3;
    all.a = 0xf;

    printf("%d\n", all.a);
    printf("%d\n", all.b);
    printf("%u\n", sizeof(all));

    return 0;
}

I compiled it with:

gcc -O0 -g test.c -o test.elf

and then used Python's pyelftools to read and print the member DIE of 'a' and 'b'. Here's what I get:
for 'a':
DIE DW_TAG_member, size=13, has_children=False
    |DW_AT_name        :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_name', form='DW_FORM_string', value=b'a', raw_value=b'a', offset=134)
    |DW_AT_decl_file   :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_decl_file', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=1, raw_value=1, offset=136)
    |DW_AT_decl_line   :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_decl_line', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=43, raw_value=43, offset=137)
    |DW_AT_type        :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_type', form='DW_FORM_ref4', value=66, raw_value=66, offset=138)
    |DW_AT_byte_size   :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_byte_size', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=4, raw_value=4, offset=142)
    |DW_AT_bit_size    :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_bit_size', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=13, raw_value=13, offset=143)
    |DW_AT_bit_offset  :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_bit_offset', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=19, raw_value=19, offset=144)
    |DW_AT_data_member_location:  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_data_member_location', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=0, raw_value=0, offset=145)

for 'b':
DIE DW_TAG_member, size=10, has_children=False
    |DW_AT_name        :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_name', form='DW_FORM_string', value=b'b', raw_value=b'b', offset=147)
    |DW_AT_decl_file   :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_decl_file', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=1, raw_value=1, offset=149)
    |DW_AT_decl_line   :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_decl_line', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=44, raw_value=44, offset=150)
    |DW_AT_type        :  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_type', form='DW_FORM_ref4', value=114, raw_value=114, offset=151)
    |DW_AT_data_member_location:  AttributeValue(name='DW_AT_data_member_location', form='DW_FORM_data1', value=2, raw_value=2, offset=155)

Concentrating on the location of each within the struct:
for 'a', the DW_AT_byte_size indicates 4 Bytes, the DW_AT_bit_offset is 19, and the DW_AT_bit_size is 13. Meaning 'a' spans on bits [19:31] of the first 4-bytes of the struct.
for 'b', the DW_AT_data_member_location indicates that 'b' is 2 Bytes in, and it's 8 bits in size, so it spans on bits [16:23] of the first 4-bytes of the struct.
Doesn't it look like these two members overlap in memory? How is it possible?

First, use the matching specifier: printf("%u\n", sizeof(all)); --> printf("%zu\n", sizeof(all)); to remove UB.

Your code doesn't compile (missing ; after struct definition). Please show your actual code in the future.

Doesn't it look like these two members overlap in memory?

They do, and you can trivially confirm that by looking at &all.b - (char*)&all (or better at offsetof(struct all_t, b)).

How is it possible?

The "size" of a bitfield doesn't mean what you think it means. From the DWARF4 standard:

If the value of an object of the given type does not fully occupy the storage described by a byte size attribute, the base type entry may also have a DW_AT_bit_size and a DW_AT_data_bit_offset attribute ... The bit size attribute describes the actual size in bits used to represent values of the given type.

Since the actual size of .a is 13 bits, the compiler is free1 to use bits [13:31] for whatever else, and it does.
Only when you increase the size of .a to 25 does the compiler increase sizeof(all) to 8 and make .a and .b no longer "overlap".

1 What the compiler must do is dictated by the platform ABI in this case (it's not free to do whatever it wishes). I am too lazy to find where in *x86 ABI it says that .b must be "packed" immediately after .a's byte boundary, but it's there somewhere.

fixed the code (I had several experimental versions). Anyway, the bit-size is not the problem - the bit-offset is.  The bit-offset of 'a' is 19 (it spans over bits [19:31]), and the byte offset of 'b' is 2 (spans over bits [24:31]), which means both 'a' and 'b' are occupying the same space in memory and it doesn't make sense to me.

ok, never mind... I found this in the DWARF document you linked to:
" A DW_AT_bit_offset attribute whose value (see Section 2.19) is the number of bits to the left of the leftmost (most significant) bit of the bit field value."
So I misunderstood the bit offset attribute (I was looking at DWARF version 6 and it's deprecated there so I just made a wrong assumption on the meaning of the DW_AT_bit_offset attribute). So now it all make sense.
